# jQuery animate() function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have trouble with this jQuery function cause it doesn't work  what it should and that is >>get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) ' , i cannot make that infinite effects

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        //move the last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks previous he will be able to see the last item.  
        //jQuery('#carousel_ul li:first').before(jQuery('#carousel_ul li:last'));  

        //when user clicks the image for sliding right  
        jQuery('#right_scroll img').click(function(){  

            //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '  
            var item_width = jQuery('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

            //calculate the new left indent of the unordered list  
            var left_indent = parseInt(jQuery('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;  

            //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '  
            jQuery('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500},function(){  

                //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '  
                jQuery('#carousel_ul li:last').after(jQuery('#carousel_ul li:first'));  

                //and get the left indent to the default -210px  
                jQuery('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});  
            });  
        });  

        //when user clicks the image for sliding left  
       jQuery('#left_scroll img').click(function(){  

            var item_width = jQuery('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

            /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */  
            var left_indent = parseInt(jQuery('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;  

            jQuery('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},{queue:false, duration:500},function(){  

            /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first item */  
            jQuery('#carousel_ul li:first').before(jQuery('#carousel_ul li:last'));  

            /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -210px */  
           jQuery('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});  
            });  
        });  
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: Hey, it is work! It is only need to put instead {queue:false, duration:500} just 500 and it will be ok! Tnx anyway :)